# How to ask questions about the languages themselves?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about two languages. I want to compare them because they are related to each other.

Which SE site fits this type of question?

in other words, an SE site for asking about the language, not about how to use it.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, it's difficult to say. ELU deals with the history of English as well as the nuts and bolts of grammar; other sites will be similar. ELU doesn't deal with the history of other languages (for example how two Latin words might be related to each other, even though both are related to English words). Your question **might** go on one or other of the language sites, or maybe even on Linguistics.SE if the question fits there. Please [edit your question](/posts/13741/edit) to be specific about the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) is very welcoming of cross-language questions - comparisons of syntax, lexical semantics, phonology, sociolinguistics, practice, theory.

[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/), however, is not as enthusiastic. Let's say that a cross-linguistic question is welcome on ELU if it is primarily about English.

For example, the etymology of an English word is entirely on-topic here but if the word was borrowed from Latin, and the question is about the provenance of the word in Latin before the borrowing, then some people grumble here that it is off-topic but it could go either way.

In the end, many questions involving two languages would be welcome on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)